Why is the thermal-induced voltage of this thermocouple different depending on direction of current


I have a vintage thermocouple type ammeter that doesn't seem to be working correctly and the fault seems to lie in the thermocouple. You can see the two larger chunks of conductive material (under the screws) to which the current source is will be attached (from the underside). Current flows from one side to the other through the two thin dissimilar conductors in the centre that are bridging the two side together. Each side has a plastic film on it on top of which is mounted an assembly so that the potential difference is measurable from the green wires.
When I send a 1 amp D.C current in one direction, I get a voltage reading of about 6 mV which deflects the needle to the 1.0 amp mark. However, if I reverse the current, I only get about 2 mV which barely moves the needle.
How is this possible? Shouldn't the same amount of power be dissipated regardless of the direction of the current? So the metals should still heat up in a similar manner and provide the same potential difference, right?
Additionally, if I apply a 1 amp RMS A.C current, the reading is about 0.7 or so if I remember correctly (I can't verify at the moment since everything is completely disassembled) which makes it seem like I'm applying a 1 amp peak-to-peak current but I'm pretty sure the digital ammeter that I'm using to check the current is giving me RMS current.
Is the meter broken or am I using it incorrectly?

Isn't a thermocouple supposed to produce a very small voltage when heated, and requires no external supply/current through it for measurements? And isn't it naturally polarized, i.e. one side being positive and the other negative?

How I understand it is... with no current applied, both metals strips are at room temperature. When the current is applied, the metal strips heat up to different temperatures causing the potential difference.

This is probably thermal converter for measuring RMS current of AC signals. No idea why it works in one way only.

This instrument is supposed to be used with AC signals only.
The problem here seems to be that the DC current produces a DC voltage drop across parasitic resistances in the circuit. This voltage drop is added to the Seebeck voltage due to construction details of this meter.
If you apply AC current instead of a DC current, the reading should be correct. The calibration is not permanent and can be altered by overloads. It is very likely that your meter reads “correctly in one direction” by coincidence only. In general it will read DC currents incorrectly in either direction.
Your meter seems to be a design that tries to bypass US Patent 2,100,260. This makes it a poor performer that is sensitive to the polarity of DC current. That is because it is a “split thermocouple” bridge meter that depends on two arms of the bridge to be perfectly balanced.
The imbalance averages out with AC signals that are sufficiently fast. The electromechanical inertia of the meter does the averaging.
It should be emphasized that the thermocouple voltage in this meter does not depend on DC current polarity. But the way the thermocouple voltage is read out adds a DC bridge unbalance voltage in series with the Seebeck voltage. This is an artifact of the construction, not of the thermocouple itself misbehaving.
There is a way to add an op-amp based DC balancer to this meter to show that this is the case.

Thanks. Nice explanation. I guess that they didn't bother to balance it for DC or lower AC frequencies because it was meant to be use for R.F. Looks like this ammeter won't be so useful to me then :(

Oh, it is pretty well DC balanced! It's just that even just a mV of DC offset - not normally a big deal - is a problem when they stacked on top of a tiny Seebeck voltage. If you got the "real deal" Weston meter constructed per 2,100,260, it would not have that problem :)
